# How do I Use OpenLayers Multi-lingual capabilities?

Tags: openlayers-2, internationalization

So, OpenLayers has a [i18n namespace](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Lang-js.html).

But in my example at the [bottom of the blog](http://openconcept.ca/blog/mgifford/openlayers-accessibility-drupal).

I am not getting the "Pan Up" which is what I would expect, but instead "PanUp", which is the string that should be translated in en.js.

I don't know enough about how this should work to debug it.  I couldn't find much in the [documentation about this](http://docs.openlayers.org/) either.

How does OpenLayers know what language to use?  When I switch to French will it know to pull out the translations of "PanUp" from the fr.js file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Say you want your OpenLayers based map viewer from English to Spanish.
>   The first step is:
>
> OpenLayers.Lang.setCode('es');
>
> To get the translation of 'Base layer' to Spanish:
>
> var translatedString = OpenLayers.i18n('Base layer');
>
> To show the translated string in the layer switcher:
>
> var layerSwitcher = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'title':
>   translatedString});  map.addControl(layerSwitcher);

[Taken From](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Localization-td3923387.html)

Here's [another good blog post](http://codingnidoc.blogspot.com/2011/04/internalization-in-openlayers-210.html).

Comment: Ok, so there is no use of setCode in the examples, so this may well be a first.  So, I've got an English setCode defined in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdAy7/).

I'm using a custom OpenLayers.js file that I built from a [fork of the 2.12 project](https://github.com/mgifford/openlayers).

And the languages are defined in [OpenLayers/Lang/en.js](https://github.com/mgifford/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Lang/en.js).

So I can't see (yet) what I'm doing wrong.  

So is there no default language that is used in the OpenLayers.js file if one isn't defined?

Comment: NOTE: So you have to add the language file separately seems [Lang/en.js](http://openconcept.ca/sites/openconcept.ca/files/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Lang/en.js) isn't brought by default into the build of OpenLayers.js